# xcodebuild - build all targets using command line

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

I'm using the command line to build all the targets in my project.
I have 3 targets in my project but the build file(.app) is getting created for one target.

Below is script

```
CONFIG="Ad Hoc"
SDK="iphoneos"
xcodebuild -alltargets -sdk "$SDK" -configuration "$CONFIG"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
xcodebuild -project projectname.xcodeproj -alltargets
```

Comment: You should be able to mark this as the solution now ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer 
but for my case i need build and archive specific target how i can do this?

Thanks